# Job Hunting after a month of working at a company

Tags: resume, job-search, new-job

So I just started a new job and it has been a month since I been here. I have 2 years in the field I am at but I am searching for another hospital to work at. The company I am currently with has a big name for itself and would look great on my resume but like I said I only have 1 month here. My last job says I stopped working there since May 2017. So what can I put on my resume that I am doing now?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here, what's your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's good to work where you want to, but there is also something said for sticking with a place for a certain duration of time.  Based on what you wrote I think professionally it would be good if you could get more time in before jumping so it looks better.  A year would be a decent timeframe, however, if it's the same company, just a different location it might be ok as it would show continuous service with the same company and there are many reasons to switch locations especially if it's the same job at a different place.